# How to replace function REPLACE() in Natively-compiled module?

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-oltp

I convert my old stored procedure (SQL Server 2016) to a natively compiled procedure and in one place I receive:

```
SELECT @name = REPLACE(@inname, ':' + @new + ':', ':' + @old + ':')
```

> Msg 10794, Level 16, State 93, Procedure usp_2, Line 101 [Batch Start Line 108]
> The function 'replace' is not supported with natively compiled modules.

How to replace the function `REPLACE()`?

Comment: The functions supported in a Natively Compiled modules are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/supported-features-for-natively-compiled-t-sql-modules?view=sql-server-ver15#bfncsp). You can only use the functions outlined there. You won't be able to use `REPLACE`, so I would suggest doing to operation outside of the procedure.

Comment: ok, it is one of ways. But what to do if I need to replace somehow REPLACE(), SPLIT_STRING() functions used in the large stored proc to do it NC?

Comment: You can't, in a Natively Compile Module. There are *only* 4 string functions you can use: `LEN`, `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`, and `SUBSTRING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical pattern is to use an ordinary a TSQL procedure wrapper and a natively-compiled sub-procedure.  The TSQL wrapper performs any unsupported operations before calling the natively-compiled procedure and handles retry in case of optimistic concurrency exceptions.